# How to fix "MultipleKeysError: Multiple aliased keys in file envvars" when running conda create command

Tags: python, anaconda

I try to create a new conda environment with in Linux Redhat system. When executing this command:

```
conda create -yn notebook_env anaconda python=3
```

It returns:

```
MultipleKeysError: Multiple aliased keys in file envvars:
  - envs_path
  - envs_dirsMust declare only one. Prefer '_envs_dirs'
```

Comment: Please share your `.condarc` file. This looks like you have `envs_path` defined in there (or possibly in the environment via `CONDA_ENVS_PATH`), whereas you should only be using `envs_dirs`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually I couldn't find my .condarc file. All I found is a path called .conda and it contains a file named environments.txt and a folder called pkgs. Inside the file environments.txt, there are different environments that I ahve created before.

Comment: Could you add the output of `conda config --show` to your question? Also, are the environment variables `CONDA_ENVS_DIRS` and/or `CONDA_ENVS_PATH` defined in the session?

Comment: Just noticed the error message references a file `envvars`. Can you find that in your system?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Actually I have deleted the conda now and try to reinstall it but the same error pops up. After running `bash Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh`, the same error `MultipleKeysError: Multiple aliased keys in file envvars:
  - envs_path
  - envs_dirsMust declare only one. Prefer '_envs_dirs'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your environment on a cluster, try to restart your session.